# Serving html file in Erlang Cowboy but it displays as text

Tags: html, erlang, cowboy

I'm trying to serve a dynamically generated html page with Erlang Cowboy, but it comes up as text in Firefox 14.0.1.

Here's the doctype and initial header tags copied from browser page source:

```
<DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset="UTF-8"><title>Welcome!</title>
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
yada yada
```

If I leave off the doctype, it displays as intended.

Bootstrap Scaffolding (http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html) calls for the html doctype.

I'm not sure if this is a problem with my html or my Cowboy configuration.

Here's the relevant portion of Dispatch in _app.erl:

```
   {['...'], cowboy_http_static,
       [ {directory, {priv_dir, cw, []}},
           {mimetypes, [  {<<".css">>, [<<"text/css">>]} ]}
```

Can someone please show the me error of my ways?

Many thanks,

LRP

Comment: `<!DOCTYPE html>` ... does it work with the leading `!`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use cowboy_static to serve a DOCTYPE html and it serves fine, with the correct mimetype.
Missing the exclamation mark: **"!DOCTYPE"** instead of "DOCTYPE"

`<!DOCTYPE html>`

See http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_doctype.asp

**Edit:** Firefox and Chrome accepts `<DOCTYPE html>` as well. So the issue is most probably the Mimetype.

Comment: This may be it! My Cowboy test bed is down at the moment, but I'll give it a try first chance. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
{['...'], cowboy_http_static,
   [ {directory, {priv_dir, cw, []}},
       {mimetypes, [{<<".css">>, [<<"text/css">>]},
                    {<<".html">>, [<<"text/html">>]}]}
```

Comment: I was so hoping that was the answer. But no dice. Thank you, though.

Comment: Here's the error message from Firefox: 
"Error: The character encoding of the plain text document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the file needs to be declared in the transfer protocol or file needs to use a byte order mark as an encoding signature." 
This does seem to suggest an issue with Cowboy config. But it's beyond my technical grasp.

Comment: Can you try to change content of your HTML file: replace `Content-Type` header with this: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">`?

Comment: Still no satisfaction. And I'm still getting the same error message. Here's the first few lines of the header: <DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"><title>Welcome!</title>
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">